# What does the term "argument lists" mean in K&R?

Tags: c, arguments

there I just got confused by a simple line in the book. The line is:

> *"because external variables are globally accessible, they can be used instead of argument lists to communicate data between functions"* .

I can't get the term **argument lists**. What is it??

- Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: The parameter you send to function

Comment: When you call a function, e.g. `f(x, y, z)`, the values between the outer parentheses are the argument list, in this case `x, y, z`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "*argument list*" is the list of arguments taken by a function.  What it means is instead of:

```
int function( int arg )
{
    return arg * arg ;
}

int main( void )
{
    function( 10 ) ;
}
```

You could do:

```
int arg ;

int function( void )
{
    return arg * arg ;
}

int main( void )
{
    arg = 10 ;
    function() ;
}
```

Why would you want to do that?  You wouldn't!  It is a *really bad idea* - ignore it, pretend you never read it.

Global data can and should be avoided and eliminated everywhere.  It has many well documented issues; in this case it renders the function non-re-entrant, so it will fail in recursive and multi-threaded applications.

K&R 2nd edition (I really hope we are not talking about the 1st edition!) is a description of the C89 programming language, not a programming style or *best-practice* guide.  Things have moved on since the introduction of ANSI-C in any case, and K&R is no longer really a recommended reference for the language.  But even in its time this would have been bad advice.

Comment: hey @Clifford, thanks your answer. Can you suggest any other book besides K&R, that would help me well to go through the language.

Comment: @UdayKiran To anyone who asks, I ask "why not learn C++ instead?". I learned C over 30 years ago, my time for learning from books, has long since passed; I cannot advise.  I don't see many new C references being published; a sign of the maturity and simplucity of the language.